# Getting Upper XPath Value Based on Lower XML value

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to get the value of SERepeatKey if ItemOID REQUIRED.REQ_V has a value of "1".
In the below case I want to return the value 2.
Is this possible with this XML? If so how?

With this I was able to do it if there was only 1 "Data" node but now with 2 I am at a loss. In XPath tester I get the below  error message.

```
string(ODM/Data/SData[@SKey='003-003'  and SiteRef[@LOID='SE 003']]/SEData[@SEOID='UNSCHEDULED']/@SERepeatKey)
```

"Unable to perform XPath operation. A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of string() (@SERepeatKey, @SERepeatKey)"

```
<ODM>    
<Data SOID="(DEV)" MetaDataVersionOID=""  >
    <SData SKey="003-003" >
        <SiteRef LOID="SE 003"/>
        <SEData SEOID="UNSCHEDULED" SERepeatKey="1">
            <FData FOID="REQUIRED" FormRepeatKey="1">
                <IGData IGOID="REQUIRED" IGRepeatKey="0" TransactionType="Upsert">
                    <IData ItemOID="REQUIRED.REQ_V" Value="0"  />
                </IGData>
            </FData>
        </SEData>
    </SData>
</Data>
<Data SOID="(DEV)" MetaDataVersionOID="" >
    <SData SKey="003-003" >
        <SiteRef LOID="SE 003"/>
        <SEData SEOID="UNSCHEDULED" SERepeatKey="2">
            <FData FOID="REQUIRED" FormRepeatKey="1">
                <IGData IGOID="REQUIRED" IGRepeatKey="0" TransactionType="Upsert">
                    <IData ItemOID="REQUIRED.REQ_V" Value="1"  />
                </IGData>
            </FData>
        </SEData>
    </SData>
</Data>
<Data SOID="(DEV)" MetaDataVersionOID="" >
    <SData SKey="003-003" >
        <SiteRef LOID="SE 003"/>
        <SEData SEOID="UNSCHEDULED" SERepeatKey="3">
            <FData FOID="REQUIRED" FormRepeatKey="1">
                <IGData IGOID="REQUIRED" IGRepeatKey="0" TransactionType="Upsert">
                    <IData ItemOID="REQUIRED.REQ_V" Value="1"  />
                </IGData>
            </FData>
        </SEData>
    </SData>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath should do what you are looking for:

```
//Data[.//IData[@ItemOID='REQUIRED.REQ_V' and @Value='1']]//SEData/@SERepeatKey
```

According to the presented XML looks like you can even omit `@ItemOID='REQUIRED.REQ_V'` and make this expression simpler

```
//Data[.//IData[@Value='1']]//SEData/@SERepeatKey
```

Comment: When I put that in the tester I got "NO MATCH!" with above xml. https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output

Comment: Ok I got the "2" with this change string(//Data[.//IData[@ItemOID='REQUIRED.REQ_V' and @Value='1']]//SEData/@SERepeatKey)

Comment: I'm sorry, forger about the `@`, now fixed that. You can even omit `@ItemOID='REQUIRED.REQ_V'`

Comment: Sorry to change the XML above but is it possible to get a list of 2,3 with the above?

Comment: Yes, this XPath will match both the `SERepeatKey="2"` and `SERepeatKey="3"`. How to get a list of these elements - depends on tool you are using here. For example with Selenium `findElement` method will return a single element, the first match on the page while `findElements` will return a list of both web elements.

Comment: ok yours works without the string() I put on it.  Thank you very much. Will do.

Comment: The `string()` is not a part of XPath, it depends on tool you are using this XPath with.