# How to Convert XPath Nodelist Attributes to Strings

Tags: xpath, nodelist

I have an XPath expression that returns the following items but need to get the values from them. (respectively "2" & "3" but entire attribute would work too)

(my xml and path expression is here: [Getting Upper XPath Value Based on Lower XML value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70773550/getting-upper-xpath-value-based-on-lower-xml-value))

```
Attribute='SERepeatKey =2'
Attribute='SERepeatKey =3'
```

This doesn't work

```
NodeList nl = (NodeList) xPath.compile(strXPath).evaluate(docODM, XPathConstants.NODESET);

for (int x = 0; x < nl.getLength(); x++){
     Node ser = nl.item(x);
     String sSer = ser.getAttributes().getNamedItem("SERepeatKey").getNodeValue().toString();
}
```

Comment: post a [mcve] please

Answer (score 0):

I removed the @SERepeatKey from the previous XPath statement to return the entire xml nodes then the above statement worked returning the "2" and "3" values.

```
<Data SOID="(DEV)" MetaDataVersionOID="" >
<SData SKey="003-003" >
    <SiteRef LOID="SE 003"/>
    <SEData SEOID="UNSCHEDULED" SERepeatKey="2">
        <FData FOID="REQUIRED" FormRepeatKey="1">
            <IGData IGOID="REQUIRED" IGRepeatKey="0" TransactionType="Upsert">
                <IData ItemOID="REQUIRED.REQ_V" Value="1"  />
            </IGData>
        </FData>
    </SEData>
</SData>
</Data>
<Data SOID="(DEV)" MetaDataVersionOID="" >
<SData SKey="003-003" >
    <SiteRef LOID="SE 003"/>
    <SEData SEOID="UNSCHEDULED" SERepeatKey="3">
        <FData FOID="REQUIRED" FormRepeatKey="1">
            <IGData IGOID="REQUIRED" IGRepeatKey="0" TransactionType="Upsert">
                <IData ItemOID="REQUIRED.REQ_V" Value="1"  />
            </IGData>
        </FData>
    </SEData>
</SData>
```